# Finding the URL for Basic installation in TFS 2013

Tags: tfs

Hi I am very new to TFS and have not installed it before. I just installed TFS 2013 using the Basic Installation that was given in the wizard. Everything is done and the installation is complete. It has created a new Server in SQL Server and hs opened up the TFS Admin Console. All the details for the server and the collections are shown here, but when I try to connect to the server from visual studio it does not connect. It says server unavailable. The state in the TFS Admin console is "Online". I am not able to modify the url in the TFS Admin Console too. I am really not sure what is going wrong here and what should be done. Am clueless about the next step. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In a web browser or in the Connect dialog in VS, it is `http://<ServerName>:8080/tfs/`

You can find [instructions for both the web and VS on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181475.aspx.).